# Clear cache in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, caching, sqldatasource

I need to manually clear the cache on a SqlDataSource with caching enabled. I've tried setting EnableChaching = false, and CacheDuration = 0 (as well as = 1) and none seem to expire the content already in the cache - although they do seem to prevent new SELECTs from being cached.

How do I manually expire that cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I just started researching this today and came across this post, this look likes the best solution:

[Simple way to invalidate SqlDataSource cache programmatically](http://beatgates.blogspot.com/2009/11/simple-way-to-invalidate-sqldatasource.html)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="x" EnableCaching="True" CacheKeyDependency="MyCacheDependency"/>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Or somewhere else before the DataBind() takes place
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
      //prime initial cache key value if never initialized
      if (Cache["MyCacheDependency"] == null)
      {
        Cache["MyCacheDependency"] = DateTime.Now;
      }
  }
}


// Evict cache items with an update in dependent cache:
Cache["MyCacheDependency"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: FYI this solution was used by me for my project that's in production now and has worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling caching (EnableCaching = false) and then forcing a new select (SqlDataSourceInstance.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments())) before re-enabling caching clears the particular combination of CommandText and CommandParameters being selected, so it's a start.

It still retains the cache of the other combinations of queries executed by the SqlDataSource, though, so this doesn't solve all of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CacheExpirationPolicy is Absolute.  Use a non-zero CacheDuration (0 means infinite cache duration).

Comment: Once I've set those to be the case, and I execute another Select(), it clears the cache of the query I'm executing, but retains all other permutations of CommandText,CommandParameters, etc. How do I clear those as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although the "EnableCaching=false".
Under heavy load, I saw some caching happening. This caching caused me to miss much data.
I found it might be related to caching.
So I use `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` on my code behind. It seems to work and after 12 hours I don't have the least missing data.